# Error installing PKI package in R

Tags: r, ubuntu, pki

I'd like to publish a slidify presentation in RPubs but it requires PKI and rsconnect packages.

I'm having this error message when trying to install PKI package in R

```
Installing package into ‘/home/juanchi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
probando la URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PKI_0.1-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 20334 bytes (19 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 19 KB

* installing *source* package ‘PKI’ ...
** package ‘PKI’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c asn1.c -o asn1.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
In file included from init.c:1:0:
pki.h:11:25: fatal error: openssl/err.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
 #include <openssl/err.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:134: recipe for target 'init.o' failed
make: *** [init.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PKI’
* removing ‘/home/juanchi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/PKI’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘PKI’ had non-zero exit status
```

with this session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 15.04

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_0.6.1        magrittr_1.5      rversions_1.0.0   htmltools_0.2.6   tools_3.2.0      
 [6] RCurl_1.95-4.7    yaml_2.1.13       memoise_0.2.1     stringi_0.4-1     rmarkdown_0.6.2.2
[11] git2r_0.10.1      stringr_1.0.0     digest_0.6.8      bitops_1.0-6      XML_3.98-1.1
```

Does someone knows what's happen here?

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL headers installed in your machine?

Comment: Install one of the openssl-devel packages for your OS

Comment: I second @hrbrmstr comment. Install `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`, as you apparently are on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks! that was the point.. then I did it with `devtools::install_github("s-u/pki")`

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu, you need to install `libssl-dev` in order to install the header files for SSL.:

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

or via Synaptic.

It's probably a good idea to also install `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, which last I checked you needed for the related package RCurl.

Comment: I confirm that this works on Ubuntu 18.04 with R 3.5.1. After installing `libssl-dev`, I could execute `install.packages("PKI")` without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but for RHEL. I have `sudo yum install openssl-devel` and problem solved!