# R - How to install "PKI" library in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I tried to install PKI library but got this error

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PKI’
```

when I already installed "openssl" and update package index

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

What else can I do to help install "PKI" library in R.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764389/trouble-installing-packages-in-rstudio-on-linux/45764510

Comment: Also, to get better help, you may want to post the whole compilation log, as in the above mentioned question for example.

Comment: Thank you. that did help. I tried to post the entire log but din't get through as it complained to have to much code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble installing packages in RStudio on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764389/trouble-installing-packages-in-rstudio-on-linux)